# Find rate when changing discount and vice-versa while keeping a fix final price

Tags: computational-mathematics

I am a web developer and building an accounting system for a client however I am almost good at programming but very bad at accounting and maths; and my client is not able to explain/communicate properly and present the equation of the calculations. So, here is the matter:

This is about creating bill of sale of products and calculating rate, discount, tax and total.
[Screenshot of a related portion of the software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy82E.png)

Suppose,

```
Original price (op) = 100
Discount (d) = 5
So, selling price (sp) (including tax) = 95
Tax rate (tr) = 15%
```

There are textboxes for showing product rate (pr), tax amount (ta) and taxable value (tv) which need to be calculated from about data. I am able to calculate these initially as following:

```
tv = sp / (1 + (tr / 100))
   = 95 / (1 + (15 / 100))
   = 95 / 1.15
   = 82.61

ta = tv * (tr / 100)
   = 82.61 * (15 / 100)
   = 82.61 * 0.15
   = 12.39

pr = tv + d
   = 82.61 + 5
   = 87.61
```

But I don't know and the client is not able to explain properly how to find other value (discount or product rate) if I change any of these two. If I change the discount then product rate and tax amount need to be recalculated, and if I change the product rate then discount and tax amount need to be recalculated. The tax rate (tr) 15 and selling price (sp) 95 are constants/fixed/readonly/non-editable.

According to this description, please give equations to find discount and product rate if any of these two is changed.

Comment: In just 5 minutes, got 2 down-votes, wow! Would anybody care to tell me the reason behind down-voting?

Comment: Can you clarify what of the above will change, what stays the same and what do you want to calculate?

Comment: @shortmanikos tax rate (15%) and selling price (95) are constants. Product rate, taxable value and discount need to be recalculated if product rate or discount is changed. I have already mentioned these in the question's description, so if these info also doesn't seems enough then please let me know what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1):

Given that **sp** and **tr** are constant and that **tv** is a calculated value from **sp** and **tr**, by definition **tv** is also constant.

And considering that **ta** also is calculated based off of constant values, **ta** is also constant in both below scenarios.

```
ta = tv * tr / 100
```

Scenario 1, for discount changes,

```
pr = tv + d
```

Scenario 2, for product rate changes,

```
d = pr - tv
```

Is there anything i am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a new pair of product rate ($pr$) and discount ($d$). Then
$ tv = pr - d $

Tax amount ($ ta $) can then be calculated in the exact same way as before from the new taxable value ($tv$). Selling price ($sp$) equals

$ sp = \dfrac{100+tr}{100} \cdot tv $.

Let's see what happens if we assume a constant selling price ($sp$) and a constant tax rate ($tr$).
Then

$tv = \dfrac{sp}{1 + \dfrac{tr}{100}}$

This means that taxable value ($tv$) is also constant. Now this implies that tax amount is also constant. In this case all that can change if we change the discount is
$pr = tv + d$
and if we change the product rate all that changes is discount
$d = pr - tv$.

Comment: No. sp = 95 is constant.

Comment: I tried some calculation. On changing either discount or rate, if I can find the taxable value (tv) then I can get the other value (d or tr). As selling price (sp) 95 is calculated on basis of taxable value (tv) as following: `tv + (tv * (tr / 100)) = sp`  `tv + (tv * 0.15) = 95`  if one can give me the equation to find the value of `tv` (from this equation) then I think it will be possible to find rate or discount from it.

Comment: @NikunjBhatt I edited my answer to account for a constant sp. You are providing the equation that you are asking for in the beginning of your post... tv = sp / (1 + (tr / 100)) but since sp and tr do not change, then neither will tv...